# Laravel 9 - Show middleware in artisan route:list

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-9

How to display/show middleware used in Laravel routing?

```
php artisan route:list
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 40):

I found the way to display.
Just add the verbose option:

```
php artisan route:list -v
```

> [image]