# Laravel 9 artisan route:list no longer displays the middleware

Tags: laravel

In earlier versions of Laravel, `php artisan route:list` gave you a tabular list of all the
tabular list that showed you all routes and their middlewares. In
Laravel I miss this information. In my case i protect users with the `auth:sanctum` middleware.

```php
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get(..)
```

**in Laravel9**

```
root@q123:/var/www/html# php artisan route:list

  GET|HEAD   /
  ...........................................................................................................................
  
  POST       _ignition/execute-solution ....................
  ignition.executeSolution › Spatie\LaravelIgnition ›
  ExecuteSolutionController
  GET|HEAD   _ignition/health-check ................................
  ignition.healthCheck › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › HealthCheckController
  POST       _ignition/update-config .............................
  ignition.updateConfig › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › UpdateConfigController
  GET|HEAD   api/profile
  .................................................................................................................
  
  GET|HEAD   api/user
  ....................................................................................................................
  
  GET|HEAD   sanctum/csrf-cookie .......................................
  sanctum.csrf-cookie › Laravel\Sanctum › CsrfCookieController@show
  GET|HEAD   v1/api/areas
  ................................................................................................................
  
  GET|HEAD   v1/api/parcel
  ...............................................................................................................
  

                                                                                                                        Showing [9] routes
```

How can I have this displayed again?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#the-route-list "By default, the route middleware that are assigned to each route will not be displayed in the route:list output; however, you can instruct Laravel to display the route middleware by adding the -v option to the command"

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks for you fast comment! If you will publish a short answer it would be accepted. Thank you!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 9 route:list middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71448710/laravel-9-routelist-middleware)

Answer (score 1):

`php artisan route:list -v`

should work

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71448710/laravel-9-routelist-middleware